# Complex Polynomial roots

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I have the polynomial $p(z)=1-z^3$, I am using mathematica to get all three roots of $p$, say $a, b$ and $c$, obviously 
$$
1-z^3=(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)
$$
However, mathematica gives a wrong answer by saying $z^3-1=(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)$. Image for reference:

[image]

Code:

```
  p[z_] = 1 - z^3
  a := Root[p[z], 1]
  b := Root[p[z], 2]
  c := Root[p[z], 3]
  ComplexExpand[(z - a)*(z - b)*(z - c)]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @ilian Of course! Silly me !! Thanks a lot, you should put it as an answer!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the coefficient of $z^3$ is $−1$, the factorization is actually $$1−z^3=−(z−a)(z−b)(z−c)$$